# Repeat Column data on each Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, rdlc

I want to Repeat my Column data on each page when i export on PDF

I am using RDLC Reporting my report generated in Landscape now i want to show my Student Name Column data on each page or multiple page..

is there any solution ?

Comment: It can't be done as far as I know. I met the same issue, and RDLC is not made for it.

Comment: You still can create another table containing only the column headers inside the page header... This is what I did.